# MySQL and PHP store and compare timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have a table in my database to store information related to each user, with each row represents a user. I hope to add two columns to it, one stores the most recent time when the user logs in, the other stores the most recent time when the user logs out.

1. As I'm relatively new to MySQL and PHP, I wonder what's the easiest way to store the current time in MySQL? Every time when a user logs in or logs out, I want to update the corresponding login/logout time column with the current time.
2. Can I compare the two timestamps using the method describe in question 1? I want to compare the last log in time with the last log out time in order to determine whether a user is currently logged in or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Here no one will code for you rather help to code. So ask where you are blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the columns type as `datetime` and update those columns with the [NOW()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) function when the user login/logout:

```
update users set login_datetime = now() where user_id = :userId

update users set logout_datetime = now() where user_id = :userId
```

In PHP you can easily take those columns and compare them or do whatever you like by using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object:

```
$userLoggedInAt = new DateTime($row['login_datetime']);
$userLoggedOutAt = new DateTime($row['logout_datetime']);

$loginTime = $userLoggedOutAt->diff($userLoggedInAt);

echo 'The user was logged in for ' . $loginTime->format('%i minutes');
```

Although I don't understand why would you use such approach, you can compare these 2 objects to check if the user is logged in:

```
if ($userLoggedOutAt < $userLoggedInAt) {
    echo 'The user is logged in';
}
```

**Question**: Using your approach, how would you set the logout time if the user is closing the browser?

Comment: What I'm currently doing is to use the time() function in PHP to generate the current timestamp, and use that as the login/logout time for a user. However, when I'm comparing the login/logout timestamps generated this way, it seems that the two timestamps are always evaluated to be equal to each other, while clearly they aren't. Do you know why this is?